# Sorting Associative Array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Struggling to sort this array:

it is database driven which gets added like so:

```
$distanceArray[] = array($attractionID => $tempDistance);
```

and the output using pre tags are the following:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array (
        [4] => 114.4
    )

    [1] => Array (
        [3] => 16.1
    )

    [2] => Array (
        [2] => 15
    )

    [3] => Array (
        [1] => 21.4
    )
)
```

I've tried this with no luck:

```
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    return $a['tempDistance'] - $b['tempDistance'];
}

usort($distanceArray, "cmp");
```

and also krsort from w3 schools

Comment: Why dont you simple use `$distanceArray[$attractionID] = $tempDistance;`

Comment: Just so you know, usort() expects the callback method to return integers. Floating point differences will cast to integers, which may result in errors during comparison. Link => http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

Comment: Post your original array structure

Comment: I thought it was best to use this method as I will be using the attractionID to query the database at a later point, but I need the tempdistance is descending order

Comment: it appears that each element of the associative array, is another associative array in itself. I think that is why the usort() method did not work. You were basically trying to sort an array of arrays.

Comment: @kkaosninja I see, if I use carlos's method of defining an array, which would be the best method of sorting it by tempdistance?

Comment: @Frog82 - http://php.net/manual/en/function.rsort.php

Comment: @CarlosAlbertoB.Carucce how is rsort gonna help him?

Comment: "This function sorts an array in reverse order (highest to lowest)." - Its not what he want? @kkaosninja

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
 $test = array( 
              array(4=>"114.4"),
              array(3=>"16.1"),
              array(2=>"15"),
              array(1=>"21.4"),     

            );

   $value = array();
foreach ($test as $key => $row)
{
    $value[$key] = array_values($row);
}
array_multisort($value, SORT_ASC,$test);

    print_r($value);
```

Answer:Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 15 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 16.1 ) [2] => Array ( [0] => 21.4 ) [3] => Array ( [0] => 114.4 ) )

DEMO:https://eval.in/398469

Comment: I have post my answer check it and let me know

Answer (score 0):

I used the following:

```
        asort($distanceArray);
        foreach ($distanceArray as $key => $tempDistance) {
            echo "$key = $tempDistance\n";
        }
```

which printed:

> 2 = 15 3 = 16.1 1 = 21.4 4 = 114.4

Thanks for your time in helping me with this question!

Comment: And there I was, preparing a detailed answer with asort(). :-D